# How to right replace array in state by another new array in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to fully replace one array by new in react useState();

For example how right to do this:

```
 const [colors, setColors] = useState(['#FF9A00', '#6276d5', '#18B8FB']);
 const onChangeColors = (newValue) => {
   setColors(prevState => [...newValue]);
 }
  return (<div style={{ width: '500px', margin: 'auto' }}>
  <h2>Current Color:</h2>
  {
    colors.map((color) => (<p>{color}</p>))
  }
    <ColorPicker colors={colors} onChange={newValue => onChangeColors(newValue)}/>
  </div>);
```

Function `onChange` of component `ColorPicker` returned array of strings for example: `['#bbbe41', '#7c67cf', '#70a385']`

Comment: Off Topic, but you should take a look at the section [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) in the react documentation. Imo. the best solution *here* is to use the array-index as a key for the colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is mutation?:**

- In essence, the concept of mutability describes whether or not the state of an object can be modified after it has been declared.
- ***Numbers***, ***strings***, and ***boolean*** values are `immutable`, meaning unchangeable or “read-only in Javascript. Hovewer, it is technically possible to change the content of object (therefore **`arrays`** itself, which causes **mutation**.

**Why not to mutate?:**

- There're couple different points why not to mutate data at all but, it's plainly more of stritctly applied best practice in order to not to cause another possible problem(s).

**Then what to do?:**

- In order to achieve immutability with `useState hook` (or similarly `setState method` with class component), it's needed to be setting state via creating a new object.
- Incase it's desired to keep previous state of an array within new one, previous state should be kept e.g. iterating over with a spread operator `...prevState`. And only after then, new value(s) should be placed right after it like below;

```
const onChangeColors = (newValue) => {
   setColors(prevState => [...prevState, ...newValue]);
 }
```

- Incase you don't want to keep the previous state of the array, then implementation is like below;

```
const onChangeColors = (newValue) => {
   setColors([...newValue]);
 }
```

To be short, the only thing for you to do differently is either;

- If you want previous state of an array, copying the **previous state** before adding the new value to new returning array,
- or only copying the new value into new returning array with
  `setState` function.

Comment: "What is mutation?" OP neither does nor wants to mutate anything. "Why not to mutate?" because it's off topic? "setting state via creating a new object" how about using the new object we receive `newValue`? "the only thing for you to do differently is keeping the previous state before adding the new value" but OP **explicitely does NOT want** to keep the previous state.

Comment: @Thomas as per your last sentence "but OP explicitely does NOT want to keep the previous state", where did you assume this?

Comment: I get this from the "fully replace" in OPs first sentence "How to fully replace one array by new in react useState()"

Comment: I'll edit my question but your answer also does not present an answer since it's not preferred way of updating state in React @Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is right.
But if you wanna simplify further use a inline arrow function:

```
  const [colors, setColors] = useState(['#FF9A00', '#6276d5', '#18B8FB']);

  return (

 <div style={{ width: '500px', margin: 'auto' }}>
  <h2>Current Color:</h2>
  {
    colors.map((color) => (<p>{color}</p>))
  }
    <ColorPicker colors={colors} onChange={newValue => setColors(newValue)}/>
  </div>);
```

Comment: enquirer asks about best practice of using arrays with useState, and furthermore your answer removes the only necessary line to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

> How to fully replace one array by new in react useState();

by just setting it `setState(newValue);`

Let's go step by step:

- `[...newValue]` this creates a copy of `newValue`. But `newValue` is already a new value (I'd assume by the name). So we don't need to copy the array.
- which leaves us with `setColors(prevState => newValue)`. but since we don't interact with `prevState` we don't need the function at all and can just pass the `newValue`.
- now we're at `const onChangeColors = (newValue) => { setColors(newValue); }` but do we really need `onChangeColors`? All it does is forward the argument it gets to `setColors`. We can simply replace it: `const onChangeColors = setColors;`
- `onChange={newValue => onChangeColors(newValue)}` that's the same as the step before, this function is also just forwarding the argument.

which effectively leaves us with: `<ColorPicker colors={colors} onChange={setColors} />`

But that's for this special case where `onChange` passes the new value, not like an event-object and you want to replace the old state, not append to it or something.

```
const [colors, setColors] = useState(['#FF9A00', '#6276d5', '#18B8FB']);

return (<div style={{ width: '500px', margin: 'auto' }}>
  <h2>Current Color:</h2>
  {
    colors.map((color, index) => (<p key={index}>{color}</p>))
  }
  <ColorPicker colors={colors} onChange={setColors} />
</div>);
```

Comment: I assume you should read [React docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state) in order to understand why it should not be used as unlike `setState(newValue);` and preferred as `setColors([...newValue])` incase previous state of the array not desired to be kept.

Comment: @ErhanYaşar I'm doing fine on both topics, react and mutation. But I don't understand your point. `setState(newValue)` will overwrite the current state with `newValue` while `setColors([...newValue])` will overwrite the current state with a copy of `newValue`; basically `newValue2`. What's the point of creating that copy of a **new** value? to get a newer one? That's like printing out a PDF and then making a copy of the printout just to make sure that the PDF document isn't changed when you write on the printout.

Comment: Well that made me think I should be starting from the **pure functions** for my answer, before mentioning `why not to mutate?` and therefore other titles. My point is ideally having ***setState as a pure function*** which is best practice like not declaring global variables even it may not be causing error in most questions/cases. Instead of using same reference to an object with `setState(newValue)`, it's better engineering practice to return `setState([...newValue])` as per it's preferred to be used in a same mentality with redux/reducers (not to mutate but returning a new state).